# Angularfire can't call database after auth

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am working on a angular2 app. It's my first one, so there are some bumps on the road, and I can't figure out this one.
I am trying to get an list from Firebase, based on the UID. So is use:

```
userList:FirebaseListObservable<any>;
constructor(private af:AngularFire, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    af.auth.subscribe(function(auth){
        if(auth) {
             this.userList = af.database.list('/listiwant/' + auth.uid);
        } 
    });
}
```

But i get nothing. I am successfully logged in, but userlist stays empty. When i try it outside the auth controller:

> this.userList = af.database.list('/listiwant/UIDSTRING');

is get the list.

```
<li *ngFor="let list of userList | async">
    {{ list.$key }} 
</li>
```

Before i used getAuth(), but that's going to be decrepated soon.

Is there something i am doing wrong, or did i misunderstood the way to use this?

Comment: In the first case are you also using the `async` pipe in the template?

Comment: Yes, in both cases i use "let list of userList | async"

Comment: Have you checked if `auth` is ever defined? Is there any error in the console? It's hard to guess what is wrong.